# Uninstall a program tile in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, uninstall, tiles

How to add "Uninstall a program" tile to Windows 8.1 start menu?

I want shortcut tile to Windows standard "Uninstall a program" window, Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features

[image: Basically, a tile shortcut to this]

I tried [OblyTile](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865), but there is no support for this action. Also tried Googling, but without success.

Comment: You want a tile/app that will allow you to uninstall other apps?

Comment: No, I want shortcut tile to Windows standard "Uninstall a program" window, Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features. Edited my question, added a clarification and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, I just did it with out any complicated steps.

1. Push the Windows key and hold it in while you push the <kbd>S</kbd> key.
2. Search will come up.
3. Type "control panel" into search.
4. Click on the control panel icon.
5. When it opens find the "program and features" icon and right click it for a menu.
6. Click on "Pin to Start" and you are done. Go to your Start page and it should be there.

Comment: Even better! Just note that Control Panel needs to have Large / Small icons view instead of Category.

Answer (score 3):

Create a shortcut to **appwiz.cpl**, or to **rundll32.exe** with the following arguments:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL appwiz.cpl,,0
```

Comment: Respect! Works great ;)